# Excel VBA script for finding specific text

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

So I'm adding a picture so you can see exactly what I need it to do -[Excel sheet picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT4dD.jpg)

So I have this script:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, G, L, N As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("F:F,K:K,M:M")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
       If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
             If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
               r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

We will talk about only what we see in the picture: so **now** when I write anything in column F it gives the date in column G, I want that it will give the date only if I write "Ja" (Yes in German) or "Yes"

Simple is that. I tried to find any "if" commands for it but none of mine worked.
Hope you can help me with that

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: Assuming the column containing "Yes" or "No" is column A, then update your or `If` line to be: `If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" And Trim(LCase(Me.Cells(r.Row, "A").Value)) = "yes" Then`

Comment: Your question is lacking context. Where is the "Yes" or "No" supposed to be found?

Comment: @tigeravatar - Does the `Me` refer to the worksheet that the code is put in?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, since this code must be in a worksheet code module.

Comment: @tigeravatar - Yeah, I know it needs to be in a worksheet, I just didn't recall seeing `Me` used outside of a userform.  Is the `me` used over `activesheet` because there's a possibility of the activesheet being different?  Do I understand that right? (Also, I guess it's shorter code than assigning a worksheet variable and doing like `mySheet.Cells()`?)

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, exactly as you say it's preferred because the `ActiveSheet` could be different (for example, the cells are updated as the result of another macro which doesn't activate this specific sheet).

Comment: Hey thank you all I have added more details + picture to my question hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better practice to achieve that also you need to set `Application.EnableEvents` back to True when you are existing the method for the next time the event will be raised, also its not bad to make some "house keeping" and use error catch if something goes wrong:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ende

    Application.EnableEvents = False


        Set A = Range("F:F,K:K,M:M")
        Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)

        If Inte Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = True
             Exit Sub
        End If

     For Each cel In Target

        r = cel.Row
        c = cel.Column

            If Trim(LCase(Cells(r, c))) = "yes" Or Trim(LCase(Cells(r, c))) = "ja" Then
                 Cells(r, c + 1) = Format(Date, "dd.MM.yyyy")
            Else
                  ' do something else
            End If
     Next

ende:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: This is a naive answer.  It is absolutely possible to change multiple cells at once, thus requiring an iteration over ranges.  For example, copying a range from one sheet to another will cause the `Target` to be that entire range of cells.  Using `Intersect` guarantees you're looking in the correct places, and iterating over the cells guarantees you're looking at one cell at a time.

Comment: @ tigeravatar  it is a `Worksheet_Change` event , the question was not about "copying a range from one sheet to another".

Comment: A `Worksheet_Change` still needs clarification on what it's looking at.  It doesn't matter that the question wasn't about "copying a range from one worksheet to another" because it remains a relevant possibility (and just one among many that can cause the `Target` argument to be a range of cells, and not just a single cell).  There is never a guarantee that `Target` will be a single cell.  To assume that it will be a single cell is bad practice.

Comment: @ tigeravatar I accept your correction , changed the answer, is this a better practice for your opinion?

Comment: Yes, better.  It still doesn't isolate which column(s)/range(s) should be looked at, and this answer doesn't address the multiple conditions requested in the original question, but that is better.

Comment: @ tigeravatar thanx (hard to concentrate where i am now)), made another change in code and explanation, i think now its working as expected.

Comment: Hey thank you all I have added more details + picture to my question hope that helps! :)

Comment: @DanielErlich please see my updated answer 1. condition reacts also to the string "ja" as desired by using the operator `or`.                                        2.  date format according to the picture (`dd.MM.yyyy` and not `dd-MM-yyyy`) by  using the method `Format()`.

Comment: @jonathana that's working great! thank you. another thing - can it be not case sensitive ??

Comment: @DanielErlich please check my updated answer, now it is not case sensitive using by using the method `Lcase()`

Comment: @jonathana Thank you! now it's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("F:F,K:K,M:M")
On Error GoTo SkipError
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In Target
        If LCase(VBA.Trim(cell.Value)) = "yes" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1) = Date
        End If
    Next cell
End If
SkipError:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thank you I have added more details + picture to my question hope that helps! :)

Comment: Change the IF statement like -- If LCase(VBA.Trim(cell.Value)) = "ja" Then

Comment: Can it be "Yes" and "Ja"?

Comment: It should be in lower case whatever you write in the column. If you write Yes, it should be "yes" and if you write Ja, it should be "ja"